# Visual Studio Code extension's document highlighter not always firing

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

My custom VS Code extension's document highlight event [registerDocumentHighlightProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDocumentHighlightProvider) doesn't fire on certain characters like: `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`. However it does fire for other characters like `A`-`Z`. Is there a way to fire document highlighting for all characters?

Working off the [Getting Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) example, I tested with this TypeScript code (my complete program):

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from HelloWorld!');
    });
    
    let docSelector: vscode.DocumentSelector = { scheme: 'file', language: 'json' };
    let highlight: Highlighter = new Highlighter();
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.languages.registerDocumentHighlightProvider(docSelector, highlight),
        disposable
    );
}

export class Highlighter implements vscode.DocumentHighlightProvider {
    provideDocumentHighlights(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken) {
        // highlight single character at cursor 
        let range = new vscode.Range(position.line, position.character, position.line, position.character + 1);
        let highlight = new vscode.DocumentHighlight(range, vscode.DocumentHighlightKind.Write);
        return [ highlight ];
    }
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Debugging the extension in VS Code, I tested with this JSON file:

```
{
  "test": "[`${SOMEFUNC(param1)} etc.`]",
}
```

A breakpoint in `provideDocumentHighlights` would not fire when the cursor was on characters: `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `)`, but would hit breakpoints on `A`-`Z` characters.

Comment: In the documentation for `registerDocumentHighlightProvider` it says:  "Multiple providers can be registered for a language. In that case providers are sorted by their score and groups sequentially asked for document highlights. The process stops when a provider returns a non-falsy or non-failure result."  Maybe there is another highlight provider that is returning a non-falsy result before yours is called.  I don't know what "sorted by score" means exactly, but see if you can get yours to always be first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @scottfrazer I got the score by calling `let score = vscode.languages.match({ scheme: 'file', language: 'json' }, document);` from `provideDocumentHighlights` and got score of 10, which I think is the highest. So I think VS Code's own score is winning - VS Code is the first provider to return non-falsy. I'm going a different direction now, looking into extending the JSON "programming language" via [syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide), I'll see how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discarded the `registerDocumentHighlightProvider` approach. Instead, I got matching parenthesis highlighting working using [Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)'s injection grammar and embedded languages, as well as [Language Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide). Here's my full solution in case others find it helpful.

**./src/extension.ts** - removed `registerDocumentHighlightProvider` from my main program:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from HelloWorld!');
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
export function deactivate() {}
```

**./package.json** - added languages and grammars to `contributes` section

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "customscript",
        "extensions": [ ".customscript" ],
        "configuration": "./customscript.language-configuration.json"
      }
    ],
    "grammars": [
      {
        "language": "customscript",
        "scopeName": "source.customscript",
        "path": "./syntaxes/customscript.tmLanguage.json"
      },
      {
        "scopeName": "customscript-json.injection",
        "path": "./syntaxes/injection.json",
        "injectTo": [ "source.json"],
        "embeddedLanguages": {
          "meta.embedded.customscript.expression": "customscript"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**./customscript.language-configuration.json** - added configuration file so VS Code matches parenthesis

```
{
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        { "open": "{", "close": "}" },
        { "open": "[", "close": "]" },
        { "open": "(", "close": ")" }
    ],
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ]
}
```

**./syntaxes/customscript.tmLanguage.json** - added grammar file for my custom script language

```
{
  "scopeName": "source.customscript",
  "patterns": [{ "include": "#expression" }],
  "repository": {
    "expression": {
      "begin": "\\[",
      "beginCaptures": { "0": { "name": "punctuation.expression.open.customscript" } },
      "end": "\\]",
      "endCaptures": { "0": { "name": "punctuation.expression.close.customscript" } },
      "name": "meta.embedded.customscript.expression"
    }
  }
}
```

**./syntaxes/injection.json** - added injection file that links together the custom script and json

```
{
  "scopeName": "customscript-json.injection",
  "injectionSelector": "L:string.quoted.double.json",
  "patterns": [ { "include": "source.customscript" } ]
}
```

The **package.json** and the **customscript.tmLanguage.json** share the embedded scope `meta.embedded.customscript.expression` which helped make everything work. Here's the result running in VS Code debugger and with test.json mentioned in the question:
[image]